# alternative to zoom that all browsers support

Tags: html, css, mobile, zooming

I'm making a prototype sight currently that is static (as in when the screen is resized smaller such as 480 pixels the sight does not responsively adjust its elements ). I actually don't want the sight to be responsive I want it to behave as apple.com does. Apples site is a large zoomed out overview of the site allowing the user to zoom in on what he/she wishes to. Whenever my sight is loaded on my iphone it is zoomed in to a tip corner of the site. When I apply zoom:.5 to the css it zooms out just as much as i would like it to in IE and chrome but does not in Firefox. Obviously that's a major problem being firefox is a very popular browser and i am having difficulties finding an alternative. If any one could offer any amount of alternatives (even using javascript) it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to set the viewport meta.

Add the following to the `head` section of your site:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

This will set the initial zoom to fit the entire page, while allowing users to zoom as they please.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite easy...
just do all your code in old fashioned pixel measurements 
and nothing will resize and it wont be responsive at all